# Import Javascript Library Into TypeScript For StencilJs

Tags: typescript, stenciljs

I have included the following js library in my project:
[Particles.js](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/). Now in my component I import it and load it like this:

```
import { Component, h } from '@stencil/core';
import * as particlesJS from 'particles.js';

@Component({
    tag: 'app-home',
    styleUrl: 'app-home.css'
})
export class AppHome {

    componentDidLoad() {
        particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particlesjs-config.json', function() {
            console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="particles" class='app-home w-full h-full fixed bg-blue-200'>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when I build and run my code I get the following error:

> TypeError: "undefined is not a function"

`particlesJS` always seems to be undefined for some reason even though I have imported it at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`particles.js` does not export any variables but instead sets a variable on the global `window` object, so you can't import it like this. Instead try

```
import 'particles.js';
```

Then you can access it directly from the `window` object:

```
window.particlesJS.load(...)
```

Related issue: https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/issues/265

Comment: Thank you soo much! This really helped. Had to use ```window["particlesJS"].load(...)``` coz typescript kept underlining .particleJS. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can importing js functions to the ts file with `require` helping

```
const particlesJS = require('./particles');
```

But all functions should be exported like module.exports in the particles.js